# Undefined method `remember' for # Rails tutorial Lesson 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following Michael Hart's tutorial to learn rails https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-remember_me but I get the undefined method 'remember'.

I searched for this error and found some solutions but none fixed the error for me so apparently I am getting a no method error in the Sessions_Controller because my remember method is undefined here is the code for my remember method

Sessions_Controller

```
module SessionsHelper


 def log_in(user)
     session[:user_id] = user.id
 end



 def remember(user)
     user.remember
     cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
     cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token

 end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end


def remember_token
    self.remember_token = User.new_token # self sets remember token attribute

    update_attribute(:remember_digest,User.digest(remember_token))
    # creates a random string of digits
end
end
```

So how do I fix the No method error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have a typo in your code. From the link you provided, it should be `def remember`, not `def remember_token`. :)

Comment: Wow,that was really stupid from me sorry for the question(I am a newbie),thanks though.